# is it possible to insert data into mysql in a hidden format?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert data into mysql in a hidden format?

I did not want to insert in encrpted format, because encryption and decryption take time.

I just want to insert data into tables which will not seen by others, but can be retrieved via query.

Comment: Either you encrypt your data or ultimately it *will* be read by others.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as "hidden tables". You should go with encryption. The performance impact can be ignored considering the security improvement you get.